# Hover to reveal Tabs Content

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation, mousehover

I need this function for tabs I'm creating. So far there is an active tab where the content is displayed by default.

I want content to be revealed on the `mouseover` event and content to be hidden on the `mouseout` event. I don't want an active tab.

This is how the tab is by default:

```
 <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
  <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <p>This is the first panel of the basic tab example. You can place all sorts of content here including a grid.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
    <p>This is the second panel of the basic tab example. This is the second panel of the basic tab example.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel3">
    <p>This is the third panel of the basic tab example. This is the third panel of the basic tab example.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel4">
    <p>This is the fourth panel of the basic tab example. This is the fourth panel of the basic tab example.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What jQuery/javascript code have you tried?

Comment: I was looking for Zurb Foundation function to do this. I can't add jquery ui externally and I was to told Foundation has almost all Jquery UI functionalities. But I can't get any Foundation rules that can do this for me.

Comment: Did my answer help? If not, please let me know why, thanks.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle. I linked to the wrong one initially.

Answer (score 0):

Your html isn't quite right. `data-tab` should be `data-tabs` and the class that indicates whether or not a tab is active is called `is-active`.

Once your html structure is correct, you could programmatically select a tab using the `selectTab` method Foundation provides:

```
var target = document.getElementById("all-tabs");
var options = {}; //Define options e.g. "option1" : "value1", etc.                                  

var elem = new Foundation.Tabs($(target), options);

$('.tabs-title').on("mouseover", function() {
  //Find the associated panel id.
  var panelId = $(this).find("a").attr("href").substring(1);
  var tabContents = document.getElementById(panelId);
  //Use the "tabs" object to select the associated panel.
  elem.selectTab($(tabContents));
  //Show the tab contents.
  $(tabContents).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  var panelId = $(this).find("a").attr("href").substring(1);
  $(this).find("a").attr("aria-selected", "false");
  var tabContents = document.getElementById(panelId);
  //Hide the tab contents.
  $(tabContents).hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/aad7qy6n/)**

Comment: Hi @Yass,Thanks for the answer. I don't want an active content. I want the content to reveal only when user clicks or hovers the tab. Can you give an advice.

Comment: Click on the "Fiddle Demo". The tab content is revealed on mouseover and hidden on mouseout. There is no active tab.

Comment: Hi @Yass Thanks for the help. It works fine.Now what I need is let links(lists) in the ul with the class tabs center in the page. So I wrapped the ul in a div and gave text-align:center, but it didn't work. I also gave the ul text-center foundation attribute but that also didn't work;. Do you have any idea what I should do? Thanks

Comment: @KwasiKumi You need to wrap the content in the panels with a class of `text-center`. Please see the updated fiddle. Also, please consider accepting my answer if it has helped, thanks :)